# cannot insert duplicate key row in table with unique index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am debugging a stored procedure which gives me the following error when executed:

```
2601: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TABLEXYZ' with unique index 'ABCKEY_PRIMARY'. The duplicate key value is (abc123).
```

There is no data being inserted in dbo.TABLEXYZ through the sproc I am executing, I also looked if there was any trigger which updated dbo.TABLEXYZ, but there was none. Any tips on how to approach debugging a complex sproc? Where else should I look to find the culprit?

Comment: start with SQL Profiler, look for SP:StatementStarting and SP:StatementComplete events. If this is a live system, you'll want to be careful about the performance impact of doing this.

Comment: When you execute the procedure and get this error message it ought to tell you the line number and procedure name responsible.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the error happened in one of the sub-sprocs. Here's my approach:

1. Turn on the Execution Plan (Query menu > Include Actual Execution Plan)
2. Run the sproc. When it errors out, you will have an extra tab call Execution Plan
3. Scroll down to the last execution plan. Thạt's likely the statement that caused the error. The statement's text is provided.

Now scan your database to see where that statement is located.